# How to set the selected options in multiselect with javascript

Tags: javascript

Alright, so this question has definitely been asked before, and I was actually able to find an answer to my question in jquery and when I tried to implement the answer I couldn't get it to work. I would just rather do it in java-script so.....

I'm reading a string of text separated by commas from a DB, and I want to translate those into selected options in a multiselect box.

All I've been doing up to this point is trying to get the browser to select a single option which matches a hard-coded string when I click a button but I can't even get that to work. But I figured that since I'm asking the question, I might as well write out the whole script so you can see it all and maybe catch any other problems I can expect to have...lastly, how can I get this to run on the page's load? Sorry if this is redundant and rudimentary but I'm very new to JS and finding existing answers to questions to be of little help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So, I found that I can get the assignment to work if I use 'select.options[i].value=true' (boolean instead of string) per Asad's answer. However, I am using Harvest's Chosen multiple select control: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

The script will not work when I have assigned the chosen class to the control. I know that the control is calling on JQuery, is this the reason why? Is it possible to get it to work? Thanks again.

```
function selectitems() {
  var select = document.getElementById("multiselectid");
  var array = stringFromDB.split(",");

  for(count=0, count<array.length, count++) {
    for(i=0; i<select.options.length; i++) {
      if(select.options[i].value == array[count]) {
        select.options[i].selected="selected";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Other than declaring `i` and `count`,  you just need to use the correct value type: `select.options[i].selected=true` since the selected property (and attribute) is boolean. You should set them all to `false` initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `for` loop has two syntax errors. Try checking the console in your browser

```
for(count=0, count<array.length, count++) {
```

should be:

```
for(count=0; count<array.length; count++) {
```

Notice the change of "," to ";" after the `count=0` and `count<array.length` parts.

Also, you might want to use `for(var count=0` and `for(var i=0` so that the `count` and `i` variables are not declared globally.

Comment: @Caderade No problem. And as I pointed out in the other deleted answer, if you use use `$("#multiselectid").trigger("liszt:updated");` after you fix the `for` loop problems, it should regenerate the items in the chosen control.

Comment: @Caderade Also, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKrGT/ - if you're already using jQuery, you might as well use it for something simple as setting the selected options for a select element.

Comment: HOLY CRAP! Thanks Ian! I don't know how the heck you figured that out so quickly but it did the trick! Thanks a ton! And I was wondering what happened to that other answer and its string of comments. I didn't realize it was deleted. But real quick, how would I make this run on page load? Is it as simple as putting the script at the end of the body? Cause that doesn't seem to do it...

Comment: And with that JFiddle, I noticed its using the index of the multiselect, any chance there is a 'Indexof' equivalent for Jquery so I could enter in the option's values instead of indeces? Because again, I am matching up the values of the options to the string array from the DB, so I don't really know what the index is at that point. Though I guess I could write another script to do this

Comment: @Caderade Haha no problem. Well if you want it to run on page load, you have to call it. I'm not exactly sure of the rest of the structure of your code, but you probably need to put `selectitems();` right before your `</body>` tag or in `$(document).ready` (which can be anywhere on your page, globally). This function can also technically be anywhere on your page as well. It just depends on where/when you call it.

Comment: @Caderade Ahh yes, you're right. Sorry I didn't notice that problem with the index. Let me try to come up with something simple

Comment: Sweet I appreciate it! and I don't know if the extended comments are appropriate (I'm new to stackoverflow as of like 3 hours ago) but I don't know how to message you and it also looks like I don't have enough rep to move it to a chat or vote your rep up. I'm surprised I was able to even ask a question. Anyways, the script works on the page load using your '$(document).ready' trick which I only knew how to use because I was already using it for the chosen control. Thanks for like the 4th time

Comment: @Caderade Yeah I don't know, technically they're not, but who cares. They're just comments. Yeah, I think all you're basically allowed to do for awhile is ask questions and accept them, then you can do more. So here's a fiddle of what you could use with jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/ZKrGT/1/ , where the original two `for` loops should work just as fine. Of the two methods in the fiddle, I'd prefer the second - it's exactly what needs to be done. I'd use an `.each` for more generic operations, where `prop` has its purpose built right into it.

Comment: That's hilarious. Sweet man I really appreciate it! To be honest (don't judge me on this one), I don't understand why that JQuery works haha, but as long as the browser gets it that's all that really matter I suppose. You were more than helpful today and if I could vote you up, I really would. Keep it real.

Comment: @Caderade Seriously no problem. And don't worry about the upvotes - not important...thanks though. Even though you may not understand, here's a quick explanation - it finds the `select` element by id, finds its `option` descendants and loops through them (automatically). For each one, it sets the property "selected" based on the return value of the function you pass to `.prop` (or just loops through each with `.each`)...where `this` refers to the current element in the loop. The `.indexOf() > -1` just means "if it's found in the array"...setting the property based on its result.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I'm going to try to address all the parts of your question in my answer.

As Ian had mentioned, there is a syntax error in your `for` statement.

On second thought I'll give the code then do the explanation. I have included the entire HTML document for purposes of clarity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-CA>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>JavaScript in multi-select</title>

    <script>

    function selectItems(stringFromDB) {
        'use strict';

        var select = document.getElementById("multiselectid"),
            stringArray = stringFromDB.split(","),
            count = 0,
            i;

        for(count = 0; count < stringArray.length; count += 1) {
            for(i = 0; i < select.options.length; i += 1) {
                if(select.options[i].value === stringArray[count]) {
                    select.options[i].selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        'use strict';

        // The "string from DB" would be the parameter here
        selectItems( 'hockey,volleyball,football');
    }, false);

    </script>

    <body>
        <div>
            <select id='multiselectid' multiple>
                <option value="hockey">Hockey</option>
                <option value="golf">Golf</option>
                <option value="volleyball">Volleyball</option>
                <option value="football">Football</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Now for the explanation.

1. Instead of using the traditional `onload` event attribute on the body element to run the script on page load (as you had wanted), I attached an event handler with the event `load` to the `window` DOM element. Event handlers are more useful as they help separate the JavaScript from the HTML (and many other reasons). You can read more about event handlers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener
2. In the function `selectItems()`, I have put all of the variables onto one declaration to keep the code clean.

   <strike>3. To avoid potential issues with arrays, I have called the variable `stringArray` instead. `array` is a reserved word in JavaScript and could cause issues with some browsers, although I'm not completely sure which ones (if any).</strike>
3. ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS use `===` instead of `==`. That way you are sure the comparison is strict and correct (i.e. both things being compared are of the same type, in this case: strings).
4. It is a good idea to force the handling of your JavaScript functions in strict mode by using `'use strict;'`. This way the browser will stop (and throw exceptions) if it detects something that is not allowed, and thus allowing you to write better JavaScript code.

Hope this helped, feel free to ask more questions if you're still confused!

Comment: `1.` I'm not sure how using `addEventListener` helps separate Javascript from the HTML more than something like `.onclick`. `2.` One declaration isn't necessarily cleaner, especially when you make it one large line. `3.` "array" is not a reserved word..."Array" is...Javascript is case-sensitive. `4.` `===` is not always the correct choice - this is the perfect example because some people may not be sure what `.value` returns (which is always a string) or `.split`, but if you're comparing them, there's no reason not to use `==`.

Comment: `1.` Initially the OP wanted to "do it in java-script[_sic_]" so in that case `addEventListener` would be the alternative to `onload`. But with jQuery then `$(document).ready( function() { ... });` already separates the JavaScript from the HTML. `2.` You can put it on multiple lines, but IMO one declaration is cleaner. `3.` I stand corrected. `4.` `===` is the correct choice. Since `.val()` and `.value` returns strings, you should be comparing a string with it.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 - Thanks for the post - the variable declaration piece is definitely cleaner and making the string the parameters of the function and doing the split inside makes a lot of sense. The reason I asked for JS was because it's easier for me to understand...the Jquery is just so foreign. Although I will say, did end up using Ian's $(document).ready idea because I was already using it (I didn't even realize it). Again....I'm pretty new. Really appreciate the help though.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 `1.` True, but there isn't really a difference of "separating the Javascript from the HTML" - they both do it the same way...although I do agree that `addEventListener` is the better choice for binding events. `2.` There's plenty of debate on how to declare, but another option that I do like is using one `var` statement, but putting a newline after each "," so that the individuals are easily seen and line up. `3.` Just wanted to point it out. `4.` If you know you're comparing strings, then there's no difference between `===` and `==`. Not trying to nitpick